# How to display currencies and languages depending on the country?

Tags: localization, prestashop

Can I display currencies and languages depending on the country in prestashop. If yes, how?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can, if you know how to code.

But in which context ? what language ? php ? js ? in your tpl ?
Be more explicit.

For example, you can find the language with this php line :

```
$this->context->language->id;
```